# CI creating multiple sessions

Tags: php, codeigniter

My CI application has been working fine.
On my localhost it works properly and on the live site, CI keeps generating sessions every time there is a page refresh.
I've updated the sessions table on database to accommodate longer user_agents.
What could be the cause of this?

Comment: do you have a form on the page? if so it could be the csrf cookie regenerating. also look at the config.php file any ensure you don't have anything set to strictly.

Comment: The csrf cookie is not turned on

Answer (score 0):

on your form page, you isn't make a condition if session is null or if you have a session,

if the form refresh, it will looping to make a new session.
so that's the problem

and then, if you want to delete a session you can

```
$this->session->unset_userdata($yoursession);
```

don't make a cookie i think that's not secure but if you learn a secure programming i think i will be secure ^_^